# Genymotion not running (open GL error) when trying to run in Windows 7 virtualbox VM

Tags: android, opengl, android-emulator, virtual-machine, genymotion

I am running [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) in Windows 7 (the Windows 7 32bit is a virtual machine itself). I have 2D and 3D acceleration enabled in the VirtualBox settings for my windows 7.

Anytime I try to start a Genymotion instance (any android version any phone model), I get the open GL error below.

The error message in the image:

```
Unable to start the Genymotion Virtual Device
Unable to initialize the openGL renderer library
Check if your video card support openGL 2.0. If no, then Genymotion virtual device can not start. if yes, may be you should update your video card drivers.
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Genymotion is using virtualisation, it does not work from a virtual machine.
You need to run it from your host.